# Visual/debugging enhancements for Oracle SQL explain plans?

Tags: sql, oracle, eclipse-plugin, sql-execution-plan

I am using *Eclipse* (and its *Data Tools Plugin*) for DB/BI development and like to have some more **visual/debugging aid** in examining huge explain plans with e.g. up to 500 lines, e.g.:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation                                             | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                      |                              |  4077K|    21G|       |  7224K  (3)| 00:04:43 |
 |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                                       |                              |     1 |    15 |       |            |          |
 |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                 | TAB1                         |     1 |    15 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                                   | IDX_FK_1111111111            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |   4 |  SORT AGGREGATE                                       |                              |     1 |    15 |       |            |          |
 |*  5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                 | TAB1                         |     1 |    15 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                                   | IDX_FK_2222222222            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |   7 |  WINDOW SORT                                          |                              |   153 |  5967 |       |    32   (7)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  8 |   HASH JOIN                                           |                              |   153 |  5967 |       |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |
 ...
```

It would be **nice to stay in Eclipse** so I do not have to setup/change environments.

(I think *SQL Developer* and/or *Toad* had some graphic explain plan viewer with hierarchic collapse/expand functionality where there is also some *Toad* Eclipse Plugin available that I did not like because it was quite intrusive regarding project manipulation.)

But please **feel free to add other answers for similar tools** and maybe screenshots **for users with similar needs but different environments**.

Comment: I had problems with Oracle's *OEPE Eclipse Plugin*, but it had a nice context menu text and graphic explain plan feature: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following simple **regex find/replace strings** applied to the text explain plan one can get a nice result:
(e.g. enabling/pushing the `Editbox Eclipse Plugin Button` in an explain-plan-containing *Editor (View)* in *Eclipse* - any other editor with similar block display/highlight features will also do)

**find: `^( \|[^|]+\d \|)(\s+)`**

**replace: `$2$1`**

will produce the following output (moving the operation indentions to the beginning of each line):

[image]

to get this kind of coloring one has to adjust [***Editbox***](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editbox) (`Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences-> Editbox -> Others`) this way:

- **`Highlight selected box:`**

  - **`color <Custom> <Red>`**, **`width <2>`**
- **`Color levels: 14`**
- **`Gradient tool:`** (e.g.) **`from color <white> to`** & **`<dark green>`** (and maybe push `Generate`)

[image]

(By the way: Hovering over such a block one can press **`ALT+Z`** which will **text-select the whole block** e.g. for easy copy/paste. (on appropriately indented SQLs also useful for partial code execution))

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to use is SQL Monitor.

https://sqlmaria.com/2017/08/01/getting-the-most-out-of-oracle-sql-monitor/

Comment: thanks! looks good. although it looks as if one has to set it up (as web application server) or at least start it on the oracle host, which may not easily be possible?

Comment: You do not need to set it up. It’s on by default. If you want to watch the queries live, then you need to use either EM or EMEcpress. But if you just want to view the final output, just generate the html file and open in a browser :)